# 301 redirect, conflicting with RewriteRule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

We did some maintenance today, and moved our web forums from /forums into the root folder of the domain.

We put in a redirect 301 in a .htaccess file:

```
Redirect 301 /forums/ http://www.ourforums.com/
```

However, we used to have some links that contained duplicate /forums folders. I.e. www.ourforums.com/forums/forums/forum.1

Obviously the redirect from above now leads to /forum.1, which odes not exist. I would like the old link to actually point to www.ourforums.com/boards/forum.1. I attempted to use something like:

```
RewriteRule ^/forums/forums http://www.ourforums.com/boards/ [NC,R=301,L]
```

Regardless of what I tried though, the Redirect seems to supersede any RewriteRules I put in the same file, regardless of whether I place them before the Redirect.

Is there any way I can somehow ensure the RewriteRule is handled before the Redirect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manually adding redirect statements like so seems to do the trick for me:

```
Redirect /forums/forums/forum.1 http://www.ourforums.com/boards/forum.1
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because mod_alias (the `Redirect` directive) and mod_rewrite (the `RewriteRule` directive) is conflicting with each other in your case. Both of them play their part in the URL-file-mapping processing pipeline, where URI's get processed, rewritten, flagged, and eventually mapped to a resource and a response. You have a `Redirect` rule which is getting applied and the response is being flagged as a redirect. The thing about the `Redirect` directive is that it connects 2 path nodes together, meaning:

```
/forums/
```

is connected to

```
http://www.ourforums.com/
```

So anything below the `/forums` folder ends up getting redirected as well. This is why it's catching `^/forums/forums`.

You can either stick to just mod_rewrite or use a `RedirectMatch` that excludes `/forums/forums`:

```
RewriteRule ^/forums/forums(.*)$ http://www.ourforums.com/boards$1 [NC,R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/forums/(.*)$ http://www.ourforums.com/$1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

or

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/forums/(?!forums)(.*)$ http://www.ourforums.com/$1
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Neither of the suggestions seem to work, but I found that I can generate manual redirects for all the individual forums. It's not my prefered solution, but at least it works and luckily it's something I can script rather than having to do manually.

Comment: @user569711 It just occurred to me that you have the `.htaccess` tag, the rewrite rules aren't going to work, they need to have the leading slash removed to work in htaccess, e.g. `RewriteRule ^forums`

Comment: Thanks again. I tried it, but still no luck. I appreciate you taking the time, though.

Answer (score 0):

I had a somewhat similar problem. I was trying to add redirects from cpanel while I already had some rewrite rules written in my .htaccess file. The error I got was "No maching tag for " What I ultimately did was that kept a copy of my existing rules and cleaned the .htaccess. Then went and added all the redirects that I needed from cpanel, and then at the end put back my own rewrite rules in the end of the file. That worked for me