# RewriteRule conditions for 301 redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have to re-name part of a URL, which is going to affect dozens of web pages:

http://www.example.com/old/web-page to http://www.example.com/new/web-page

So far I have:

```
RewriteRule old/(.*) http://www.example.com/new/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But I've read that [RewriteRule can clash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12824633/301-redirect-conflicting-with-rewriterule/12828762#12828762), which I'm using in .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

So, I have two questions: is the RewriteRule correct; and am I going to experience a clash of some kind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place your `301` rule just below `RewriteEngine On` line:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule old(/.*)?$ /new$1 [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response. As you can imagine, I have other things to do first (change the actual URL structure for one), but I'll vote up and accept your answer if everything works out.

Comment: ok sure let me know if you run into any problems using these rules.